# Virtual machine set-up using Vagrant, but started via VirtualBox UI

Tags: hadoop, vagrant

Hadoop & Vagrant: If I set up a new VM using these two packages, is the VM available for starting with VirtualBox or do I always have to use `vagrant up`?

Answer (score 0):

When you first create the VM, you will need to use `vagrant up` since VirtualBox has no ability to read a Vagrantfile. Once your VM is up and running, you could stop and start it using VirtualBox. However, Vagrant can perform the same operations as VirtualBox and has a lot of advantages on top of that.

First let's discuss how Vagrant can do what VirtualBox can do. You can use `vagrant suspend` to put the VM in a saved state, `vagrant resume` to start it again, `vagrant halt` to power it off, and `vagrant destroy` to delete it. You can also use settings in Vagrant's VirtualBox provider to [modify your VM's memory, CPUs, and more](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/configuration.html). You can also change the [network settings](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/networking.html) and [synced folders](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html). And this gives you the advantage of defining all of these settings in code which can be checked into a revision control system such as Git.

On top of all this, Vagrant has support for [provisioners](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/basic_usage.html). These range from something as simple as [shell scripts](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html) to full blown configuration management tools such as [Puppet](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/puppet_apply.html), [Chef](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/chef_zero.html), [Ansible](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html), and [Salt](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/salt.html). Just like you can define your VM's VirtualBox settings in code, you can define the entire creation process including installing packages, managing services, and customizing files. And you can make changes at any time and apply them using `vagrant provision`.

So getting back to your question... yes, you can control your VM directly with VirtualBox, but you'd be missing out on the rich feature set of Vagrant.